# Is there an ETF which tracks BSE or NSE among ELSS funds eligible for tax deductions under 80C?

Tags: india, tax-deduction, etf, nse-india

Is there an ETF which tracks BSE or NSE among ELSS funds eligible for tax deductions under 80C? I see a list of ELSS funds [here](http://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/performance-tracker/navs/elss.html), but do not see consolidated listing of expense ratios or fund types..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an ETF which tracks BSE or NSE

There is no ETF [Exchange Traded Fund]. ETF's allow withdrawals at will which is against the 80C eligibility criteria. There should be a lock-in of 3 years.

There are quite a few regular ELSS, but very few fund houses Index based. Franklin has launched such a scheme. However these are no popular. ELSS as these have a lock-in of 3 years, allows a fund manager to better manage the fund and beat the index in terms of returns and hence most / all ELSS are actively managed funds.